# How can I change the veins example code so that the communication happens through VLC using Veins VLC?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm new to OMNeT++ and veins, and I have done some projects using veins only. Now I have installed veins-vlc, which I can use to make vehicles communicate through vlc. But I don't know how to start with this. I tried using SimpleVlcApp.cc instead of TraCIDemo11p.cc but it doesn't work. Please help.

P.s.: When using vlc, are we only able to communicate with one node at a time?